# Embedding a web application inside Eclipse/IntelliJ

Tags: java, web-applications, eclipse-plugin, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have a couple of questions regarding Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA support for building a plugin that can...

1. show (and accept user input to) an interactive web application (with drag-and-drop diagram editing functionalities similar to Visio/OmniGrapffle/Inkscape) inside the main workspace (the biggest space to the right:)) of the IDE.
2. interaction with the web application (e.g. clicking on a box in the diagram) will trigger some action in the IDE (e.g. show a corresponding source file, or opening a dialog to create a new class).

In other words, I plan to let the web application manage most of the GUI aspects to overcome the limitations of Eclipse and IDEA in terms of animation, or flexibility in terms of showing nice graphics.

To this end, the web application needs to be able to communicate with the services/other plugins provided inside the IDE.

Browsing the web and StackOverflow revealed to me that Eclipse supports an OSGI architecture that might enable me to write an webservice that can be accessed from a web application. But I'm not sure where to start with. Also no relevant information concerning building my plugin for IntelliJ IDEA can be found.

It would be great if you can provide me some pointers. Thank you very much.

PS: I was considering building a normal plugin, (e.g. using the Eclipse's [Graphiti](http://www.eclipse.org/graphiti/) project) but the user experience (button's shape, dialogs, properties windows, etd.) using only Eclipse platform support seems limited, as opposed to full HTML/CSS/JavaScript/etc/ supported by a web application. I might be wrong with my approach though so any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Your question should actually be closed, please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Do you have any idea and tried anything to implement interaction between IDE and webpage in embedded browser? I guess it's rather impossible.

Comment: hi Piotr, thanks for your comment. I stated in my question that I browsed the web and found out that Eclipse support OSGi architecture that may allow me to write a  service that can be accessed from a web application. This web app then can use the service to call other functions within the Eclipse environment. That's the idea. But I don't know if it's really feasible.

Comment: Your architecture will consist of eclipse plugin with services + web server (Jetty?, which HTTP port?) + web application + client side running in embedded browser in eclipse. Imagine simple scenario: user double-clicks a diagram file in project browser. You need to open (start first!) everything and open a browser with selected file. You need to register your "plugin" as an editor in Eclipse... Before creating such "sculpture" I'd try using JavaFX in Eclipse or take one more look at Java and SWT graphics.